# Trying to make magic color filter for scanned document, but not getting perfect output

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to make a magic color filter for the scanned document but not getting the desired output. In some documents text is distorted in some document, images colors get lost. In some document, text gets too thick.
I am using Laplacian of Gaussian for edge enhancement and then thresholding and at last blur the image to get the natural look.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('example_output/sample16.jpeg')
original = img.copy()
kernel_sharpen_3 = np.array([[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
                         [-1, 2, 2, 2, -1],
                         [-1, 2, 8, 2, -1],
                         [-1, 2, 2, 2, -1],
                         [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]]) / 8
img = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel_sharpen_3)
ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(threshold, (5, 5), 0)
stack_horizontal = np.concatenate((original, img), axis=1)
stack_horizontal2 = np.concatenate((threshold, blur), axis=1)
stack_vertical = np.concatenate((stack_horizontal, stack_horizontal2), axis=0)

cv2.imshow('Images', cv2.resize(stack_vertical, (700, 1000)))
cv2.imwrite("magic.jpg", threshold)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

#### Input image:

[image: Input Image]

#### My result:

[image: My Result]

#### Dersired output:

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: This question might be better suited for [dsp](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) than here. Also, it would be good to post some references as to why you think those three steps are the way to go. Why you didn't try say histogram equalization or any other techniques.

Comment: Have you tried tuning your three steps? Especially the thresholding.How did you choose the values like `120`, the values in the kernels, size of the kernels etc? Have you experimented with different values?

Comment: @Dan yes, I have tuned values of each and every function used here. Tried histogram equalization but then the place where shadow comes gets darker.